# Haskell: ternary tree average, with nested `where`

Tags: haskell, average, ternary-tree

I was trying to calculate the average of a ternary tree. It seems not possible to finish it inside one function. Is there any way to solve this question, or it's necessary to use two functions? Thanks.

```
-- define a tree
data Ttree t = Nil | Node3 t (Ttree t) (Ttree t) (Ttree t)

-- get the Ternary tree and return the average
treeAverage :: Ttree Double -> Double
treeAverage Nil = 0.0    -- empty tree
treeAverage tree = treeAverage' tree (0.0) 
           -- try to use accumulator and another function 
  where
    treeAverage' Nil _ =  0.0    -- empty tree
    treeAverage' (Node3 n left mid right) (sum/count) = 
        ((n+sumL+sumM+sumR) / (1+countL+countM+countR))  -- average
      where
        (sumL,countL) = treeAverage' left 
            -- calculate left subtree with sum and count
        (sumM,countM) = treeAverage' mid 
        (sumR,countR) = treeAverage' right
```

Comment: You do not use the accumulator correctly, this has as type a `Double`, but you thus can not pattern match it on `sum/count`. I would advise to use *two* accumulators.

Comment: Thanks, I am still trying to implement it.

Comment: If you define a `Foldable` instance for your tree, which lets you focus on the single issue of iterating over every node, you can just use the generic definition of average `sum t / length t`, as both `sum` and `length` work for arbitrary `Foldable` values.

Comment: ...Indeed you don't even need to _define_ it, you can use `-XDeriveFoldable`. However, I'd remark that it's worth considering whether it makes any sense at all to define that function. If it's really just the average _of the elements_, it seems better to make that explicit by converting to a list (again, use `Foldable` for that) and then taking the average of that. By a _tree average_, OTOH, I would rather expect something that directly averages between the recursive averages in the subtrees, not considering how many elements are in each of them. That gives in general a different result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compute an average value, you have to perform a single division at the very end of the process, something like `(allSum / allCount)`. As the division cannot be part of the recursive tree traversal process, it seems difficult to achieve what you want within a single function.

Let's start by providing a little fix for your code. It is unclear whether your auxiliary `treeAverage'` function returns a pair or a single numeric value. We can rewrite the whole thing like this, where unambiguously it returns a pair:

```
-- define a tree structure:
data Ttree t = Nil | Node3 t (Ttree t) (Ttree t) (Ttree t)
                  deriving (Eq, Show)

treeAverage1 :: Ttree Double -> Double
treeAverage1 Nil = 0.0 -- empty tree
treeAverage1 tree =
  let   (sum1, count1) = treeAverage' tree
  in    sum1 / count1
    where
      treeAverage'  Nil  =  (0,0) -- empty tree
      treeAverage'  (Node3 n left mid right) =
          let  (sumL,countL) = treeAverage' left   -- calculate left subtree
               (sumM,countM) = treeAverage' mid 
               (sumR,countR) = treeAverage' right
          in
              ((n+sumL+sumM+sumR) , (1+countL+countM+countR)) -- (sum, count)
```

and that code appears to work:

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> :load  q67816203.hs
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> leaf x = Node3 x Nil Nil Nil
 λ> 
 λ> tr0 = Node3 4 (leaf 5) (leaf 6) (leaf 7) :: Ttree Double
 λ> tr1 = Node3 2 (leaf 10) tr0 (leaf 15)
 λ> 
 λ> tr1
 Node3 2.0 (Node3 10.0 Nil Nil Nil) (Node3 4.0 (Node3 5.0 Nil Nil Nil) (Node3 6.0 Nil Nil Nil) (Node3 7.0 Nil Nil Nil)) (Node3 15.0 Nil Nil Nil)
 λ> 
 λ> treeAverage1 tr1
 7.0
 λ>
```

However, in this code, tree traversal is inextricably intertwined with arithmetics.

### Decoupling ...

The common Haskell practice would be to improve matters by *subcontracting* tree traversal to general purpose functions, that is, functions we (or the language library) would provide anyway in order to support our tree structure, regardless of any numeric concerns.

### About plain lists ...

At that point, we can look at a simpler problem: how do we compute an average for a plain *list* of numbers ?

As mentioned in a comment by chepner, you can use:

```
listAverage xs = (sum xs) / (length xs)
```

We could adapt this approach to `Ttree` objects, coming up with `treeSum` and `treeLeafCount` functions. But that would be suboptimal. In modern hardware, memory access is way more expensive than arithmetics, and `listAverage` needlessly traverses the list *twice*.

How do we get to traverse the list just once ? Well, computing an average is obviously a **fold** operation, that is you traverse a complex structure in order to produce a single value. See the [classic paper by Graham Hutton](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/fold.pdf) about the merits of fold operations.

Lists have an instance of the `Foldable` class mentioned in the comment by chepner. So the library provides, among other things, a `foldr` function for lists:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

The first argument of `foldr` is a *combining function*, which takes an accumulator value and a scalar value from the input list, and returns an updated accumulator value. The second argument is just an initial value for the accumulator.

So we can write a single-traversal list average like this:

```
listAverage :: [Double] -> Double
listAverage xs  =  sum1 / count1
  where
    cbf x (sum0, count0) = (sum0+x, count0+1)  --  combining function
    (sum1, count1) = foldr cbf (0,0) xs
```

This works fine:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :type listAverage
 listAverage :: [Double] -> Double
 λ> 
 λ> listAverage [1,2,3,4,5]
 3.0
 λ>
```

Now, can we adapt this approach to trees ?

### Tree traversal

So we need to somehow get a version of `foldr` for our trees.

We can write it manually, working our way thru the structure from right to left:

```
treeFoldr  ::  (v -> r -> r) -> r -> Ttree v -> r
treeFoldr cbf r0  Nil  =  r0
treeFoldr cbf r0  (Node3 v left mid right)  =
    let  rr = treeFoldr cbf  r0  right
         rm = treeFoldr cbf  rr  mid
         rl = treeFoldr cbf  rm  left
    in
         cbf v rl
```

Note that it is critical here to be able to specify the initial accumulator value.

So we now have a tree traversal mechanism that is fully general purpose and detached from any numeric concerns.

For example, we can use it to *flatten* any sort of (possibly non-numeric) tree:

```
toListFromTree:: Ttree v -> [v]
toListFromTree tr  =  let  cbf = \v vs -> v:vs
                      in   treeFoldr cbf [] tr
```

This can be further simplified:

```
toListFromTree tr  =  treeFoldr (:) [] tr
```

Testing:

```
 λ> 
 λ> treeFoldr (:) [] tr1
 [2.0,10.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,15.0]
 λ>
```

At that point, we can define the `Foldable` instance for trees:

```
instance Foldable Ttree  where  foldr = treeFoldr
```

and the pretty short code of the list averager above can now be used unmodified to average trees, essentially by adapting its type signature.

```
treeAverage :: Ttree Double -> Double
treeAverage tr  =  sum1 / count1
  where
    cbf x (sum0, count0) = (sum0+x, count0+1)  --  combining function
    (sum1, count1) = foldr cbf (0,0) tr
```

Now, we can do something easier. The GHC compiler happens to provide an extension, `DeriveFoldable`, that allows us to ask the compiler to write `treeFoldr` automagically. This leads directly to our:

### Shortest solution:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  DeriveFoldable    #-}

-- define a tree structure:
data Ttree t  =  Nil  |  Node3 t  (Ttree t)  (Ttree t)  (Ttree t)
                  deriving  (Eq, Show, Foldable)

treeAverage :: Ttree Double -> Double
treeAverage tr = sum1 / count1
    where
        cbf x (s,c)    =  (s+x,c+1)
        (sum1, count1) =  foldr cbf (0,0) tr
```

And I think most Haskell programmers would agree that this counts as a single function :-)

Note that it is also possible to provide `Functor` instances, hence an `fmap` function, using the `DeriveFunctor` GHC extension.

Comment: Thank you for spending time answering this question. Apart from solving the original question, I think you've done an excellent job of explaining how to derive a foldable tree and a better answer in detail, which I haven't found on StackOverflow.

Comment: Shorter-est solution: `treeAverage = uncurry (/) . foldr (\x -> (+x)***(+1)) (0,0)`, using `***` from `Control.Arrow`. Or even `foldr ((***succ) . (+)) zeroV`. — But surely we should use a strict left fold here, not a right fold?

Comment: `cbf x (s,c) = (s+x, c+1)` can be written `\ x -> (+x) *** (+1)`. but it probably should be written `cbf x (!s, !c) = (s+x,c+1)` instead. :) also `foo tr = sum1 / count1 where (sum1, count1) =  foldr cbf (0,0) tr` can be written `foo = uncurry (/) . foldr (\ x (!s, !c) -> (s+x, c+1)) (0,0)`. (ah, right, like the comment  above is saying, perhaps `foldl'` is better... (will still need the nested bangs, too))

Comment: @leftaroundabout - Nice use of Arrows, thanks ! though not necessarily  the easiest thing to understand for a beginner. Regarding left versus right fold, yes you're right, for sufficiently large trees `foldl'` is better. I 've just used right fold in the answer because `foldr` is what it takes to get a `Foldable` instance. Secondarily it makes for a short and elegant `toListFromTree` function, as `foldr (:) []`.

Comment: @WillNess - thanks, yes that's right. Using `foldl'` and strictness, you can successfully handle larger trees. I will think of complementing the answer once I fully understand the details.

Comment: re "arrows" we can just treat `***` as a combinator i.e. poitfree shortcut, with functions: `(f *** g) ~(x,y) = (f x, g y)`. the pattern may or may not be lazy in reality,  I don't know. (should be easy to check). :)